# Nuxt display data on infinite loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello i want to display data in infinite loading.
the first page display first data but after loading the data on second page not display
i use asyncData and methods to increment data page after loading

```
// page

    <my-products ref="child" :products-and-skus="productsAndSkus" @fetchMore="callApi" />

async asyncData({ $axios, store }) {
    const customerId = store.getters['user/auth/customerId'];
    if (!customerId) {
      return;
    }
    const productsAndSkus = await customerApi.getFavoritesProductsAndSkus(
      { $axios },
      customerId
    );
    return {
      productsAndSkus: productsAndSkus
    };
  },

methods: {
    async callApi(newPageAsked) {
      const app = { $axios: this.$axios };
      const customerId = this.$store.getters['user/auth/customerId'];
      if (!customerId) {
        return;
      }
      const newProductsAndSkus = await customerApi.getProducts(
        app,
        customerId,
        newPageAsked
      );

      if (newProductsAndSkus.length) {
        this.productsAndSkus = [...this.productsAndSkus, ...newProductsAndSkus];
        console.log(this.productsAndSkus); // i have a data but not display
        this.$refs.child.$refs.infiniteLoader.stateChanger.loaded();
      } else {
        this.$refs.child.$refs.infiniteLoader.stateChanger.complete();
      }
    },
    goBack() {
      this.$router.push(this.localePath('Account'));
    }
  }
```

My child component

```
<template>
<client-only v-else>
            <infinite-loading
              ref="infiniteLoader"
              :distance="800"
              force-use-infinite-wrapper
              @infinite="infiniteHandler"
            >
              <div slot="no-more" />
            </infinite-loading>
          </client-only>
</template>
<script>
 infiniteHandler($state) {
      this.page += 1;
      this.$emit('fetchMore', this.page);
    },
</script>
```

i don't display data after loading please help

Comment: What is the actual issue? What do you see in your vue devtools as `products-and-skus`?

Comment: Also, can you please post the whole `.vue` files and not just a part of it?

Comment: products-and-skus send 5 products after loading in vue devtools but display 4 products

Comment: Please update your question and put all the required info there. I cannot see any `productsAndSkus` on the child component here.